# Git: branch-x changes have become part of branch-y?

Tags: git

I don't know how it happened, but I am on a 'branch-x' and the files I have changed belong to `branch-y'.

I cannot `git checkout branch-Y` because the I have un-committed changes and I don't want to commit them in branch-x.

How can I return to branch-y with my changes intact?

Comment: You could use `git stash`. Then when you want to get them back out `git stash pop`. There's a bunch of other stashing features if you want to read the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could stash your changes:

```
git stash
```

Then checkout the correct branch:

```
git checkout branch-Y
```

And then unstash the changes in the correct branch:

```
git stash pop
```

Depending on what types of changes you made in your initial branch, you might need to use additional switches on `stash` command (e.g. `--include-untracked`). You can read more about `stash` command in [Git docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash).

Comment: Thanks - I thought stash only held things within the current branch. Guess not. Cheers